# Python class object same as "self"

Tags: python, qt

I have QT based GUI, wherein I read contents of `LineEdit` from a text file. The GUI is represented by a class (there are many such GUI selected on user's choice), whereas I want to keep the function of reading and displaying outside of class. So, for this I created an object of the said class and passed it to outer function. But, it does not display the words read from a file in the allocated boxes in GUI. Moreover when I equate the object to `self`, then only the texts are displayed. Following is the code fragment.

```
class MainClass(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_MyClass):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def fillBoxes(self):
        self.messageBox.setText("Reading File !!")
        time.sleep(2)
        classObj = MainClass()  # object
        print "entering func.." 
        ret = readFile(classObj,'REX011')
        print self, classObj

def readFile(resClass,res):
    ......functioning related to file read....
    .....
    resClass.messageBox.setText("File Read Complete!!")   # No display
```

The console output for `print` statement above yields

`<myFile.MainClass object at 0xb36682b4>`

`<myFile.MainClass object at 0xb36ac26c>`

i.e. both `self` and `objClass` are differently located. Why is this happening? should they not be co-located so that all messages are displayed. Is it OK to create the object of the class within the same class definition?
Instead of doing:

```
classObj = MainClass()  # object
ret = readFile(classObj,'REX011')
```

can I do this safely??

```
ret = readFile(self,'REX011')
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `self`? Apart from this, if you really need `MainClass()` to return the same object, then you want to implement a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`classObj = MainClass()  # object` will create another, new, instance of MainWindow(). That is not what you need. `ret = readFile(self,'REX011')` should do what you need.